# Не отображается Placeholder в поле Input

Tags: django

В полях `username`, `firstname`, `email - placeholder` отражается, а в полях `password1` и `password2` - нет.

В чем может быть проблема?

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email', '')
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Пользователь с таким e-mail уже зарегистрирован')
    return email

def clean_password2(self):
    cd = self.cleaned_data
    if cd['password1'] != cd['password2']:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Пароли не совпадают')
    return cd['password2']

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
    widgets = {
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Логин'}),
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Имя пользователя'}),
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Электронная почта'}),
        'password1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Введите пароль'}),
        'password2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Повторите пароль'}),

    }
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
        new_user.save()          
    
        return render(request, 'reg_app/main.html')
else:
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
return render(request, 'reg_app/signup.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

form.html

```
<body>
<div id="background-login"></div>
    <div class="center">
        <form class="signup" method="post">

            <a href="{% url 'main' %}"><img class="close" src="{% static 'reg_app/img/close.png' %}" alt=""></a>
            <div class="center">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h4 class="visually-hidden">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</h4>
                <div class="illustration">
                    <img class="png" src="{% static 'reg_app/img/login3.png' %}">

                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">{{ user_form }}</div>
                <div class="mb-3"><button class="btn1" type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button></div>


            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено. Нужно в функцию добавить следующий код:

````
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _

    class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': _('Логин')})
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': _('Имя пользователя')})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': _('Электроная почта')})
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': _('Введите пароль')})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': _('Повторите пароль')})


     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')```
````